# What are some ways we measure irrationality?

Tags: approximation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

**I am wondering in what ways we may quantify an irrational number's approximability.**

This came up as I was reading about *[badly approximable numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BadlyApproximable.html)*, which are those numbers $x$ such that

$$\liminf_{q \to \infty}q|qx-\{ qx\}| >0.$$

The number which the above limit converges to is known as the approximation constant, which might be described as a measurement of how closely we can approximate $x$ in denominators of growing size. Then I started reading about the *[Liouville-Roth irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number),* which is the greatest $u$ so that $|x - p/q| < 1/q^u$ for infinitely many pairs $(p,q)$ of positive integers.

Both of these numbers quantify irrationality, in some way.

So, as in my title: are there other ways we quantify approximability/irrationality of irrational numbers, or certain classes of irrational numbers (ie. quadratic numbers)?

Comment: One place to begin is [Mahler's classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Mahler's_classification). See also [*On Mahler's classification of transcendental numbers*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889378) by Alan Baker (1964) and the google search ["Mahler's classification of transcendental numbers"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Mahler%27s+classification+of+transcendental+numbers%22&filter=0).

Comment: The 3blue1brown youtube 'Music and Measure Theory'  may be relevant: If you order the rationals within (0,1) by an increasing denominator sequence, i.e. 1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 3/4, ... , where duplicates such as 2/4 = 1/2 are eliminated, you can cover the rationals by enclosing each rational by an interval of width following the successive members of a convergent sequence summing to <1 ... of which there are many. This 'orders' the rationals from 'simpler' (smaller denominator) to more complex.Irrationals close to late appearing rationals approximate 'less simply',at least in the realm of music.